# Can i use v brakes on racing bike rims?

Tags: brakes, shimano

i fitted a set of cheap "thin" (racing bike size) rims with 32 mm tyres. the fork allows even bigger tyres to be mounted. is it a problem if i fit the bike with Deore LX v-brakes ? will it brake decently ? and what handles would u recommend?

Answer (score 4):

32mm tires with v-brakes is a very common configuration on hybrids. You should have no problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your frame has the mounts for v-brakes, there is no reason why the rim should prevent you from using them.

There are a number of bicycle types which use standard road rims which are designed with v-brakes or mini v-brakes.

You do need to pay attention to the type of brake lever, since most road levers and a lot of older MTB levers are not compatible with v-brakes, or at least require mini v-brakes because of the amount of cable pull required.